# What is the expected number of trials until at least $m$ successes without repetitions?

Tags: probability

I tried to look for a similar question but didn't find the exact thing (the closest I found was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102673/what-is-the-expected-number-of-trials-until-x-successes) but AFAIK it is not the same)

I have $r$ coins that land heads w.p. $p$. I want at least $m$ heads. On the first step I toss all of $r$ coins and from the second step and on I toss only the coins that didn't land heads already.

What is the expected number of steps until I have at least $m$ heads?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the number of steps is $n$.

By that time the (expected) fraction of coins that still is a $0$ is $(1-p)^n$.

So you are looking for $n$ where $r \times (1-p)^n \leq (r - m)$. (The number of $0$ is less than or equal to the allowed number of $0$'s)

(Take a logarithm, after some rearranging of terms to have the exact answer)

Comment: thanks! but that's just a lower bound. I am looking for the exact phrase.

Comment: I think that these functions are nice enough that it will also be the exact number. E.g. if you take the example where you want 7 out of 8 fair coins to be 1, the answer is 3, as I'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

Denote this expectation by $\mu_{r,m}$. If $X$ denotes the number
of coins that get $1$ then:

$$\mu_{r,m}=1+P\left(X=0\right)\mu_{r,m}+\cdots+P\left(X=m-1\right)\mu_{r-m+1,1}$$

Here $X\sim\text{Bin}(r,p)$.

This allows you to express $\mu_{r,m}$ in $\mu_{r-i,m-i}$ for $i=1,\dots,m-1$
so a recurrence relation is found.

Success!

Comment: I think the last $P(X\geq m)$ is not needed.

Comment: @user103828 You are correct. I repaired. Thank you!